# Hidden element inheriting properties it shouldn't?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a # link that when clicked shows a hidden div.  The problem is that the text in the div also shows up as a link when it's not supposed to, anybody know why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
#hidden{
    background-color:gray;
    width:120px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:x-large;
    color:black;
    display:none;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="button"><a href="#">Toggle</p>

<div id="hidden">woot</div>
<script>

$("#button").click(function () {
$("#hidden").toggle();
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where is the div? can you post your html code? - You asked us about the div and then didn't post it ;)

Comment: To highlight code mark it in the editor, press the `{}` button.

Comment: thanks, i just clicked the button and didn't highlight it first.

Comment: you should upvote any helpful answers and check the answer that solved your problem first/best as the answer. This way other people with a similar question to yours can find the right answer easily. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You never close the `<a>` tag:

```
<p id="button"><a href="#">Toggle</p>
```

Do this instead:

```
<p id="button"><a href="#">Toggle</a></p>
```

---

The code was not [well-formed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Well-formedness_and_error-handling) (with regard to nesting) with the missing `</a>` causing the link to expand to the rest of the page (including the hidden part).

Answer (score 1):

Is it because the hidden `div` is nested inside the `a` tag? Just guessing, you should post the HTML really.

Edit: I was right, then. You should replace

```
<a href="#">Toggle</p>
```

with

```
<a href="#">Toggle</a></p>
```

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
#hidden{
 background-color:gray;
 width:120px;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-size:x-large;
 color:black;
 display:none;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="button"><a href="#">Toggle</p>

<div id="hidden">woot</div>
<script>

$("#button").click(function () {
$("#hidden").toggle();
});
</script>

</body>
</html>

Comment: @kalessin - sometimes newer users don't know that they are supposed to. Although im not sure what they think the big check mark next to each answer is though... I upvoted your answer though. nice job.

Comment: @kralco626 - Cheers, appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You din't close the `<a>` tag. You need `</a>`

```
<body>
  <p id="button"><a href="#">Toggle</a></p>

<div id="hidden">woot</div>
<script>

$("#button").click(function () {
$("#hidden").toggle();
});
</script>

</body>
```

The `<a>` tag was still open so the browser did not know when you wanted the link to end. Always make sure you close your html tags with the `/`. Either `<tagName />` or `<tagName></tagName>`